# Does a car with a hybrid engine and Lithium batteries pollute more than a car with conventional technology?

Tags: environment, road-vehicles

[You hear a lot of claims that, once you include manufacturing and battery replacement, hybrids pollute more than an efficient, more conventional engine](http://www.caradvice.com.au/110838/electric-cars-pollute-more-than-petrol-cars-report/). Are there any end-to-end studies measuring *any* type of pollution for both types of vehicles, which demonstrate that one is superior, even when the manufacturing (and pollution to generate electricity) is included for consideration?

Note, I'm not talking about comparisons to Hummers.

Pollution to include CO<sub>2</sub> and other emissions commonly attributed to and regulation in relation to the combustion of gasoline in motor vehicles.

Comment: Pollution is a vague term. Do you mean CO2 emissions, lead emissions, or something else?

Comment: How do you calculate an exchange rate, when technique A produces more of the harmful x, and technique B produces more of the harmful y?

Comment: Updated the question to be more specific -- Given the lack of response, I'm wondering if anyone has actually performed an end to end analysis for both types of vehicle.

Comment: Something that seems to have been ignored so far is the fact that electric and hybrid vehicles can recapture energy from the braking process turning it back into electricity. In fuel burning vehicles this energy is lost as heat (in the brake pads and disks)

Comment: @Tendulkar: I believe that is incorporated into the fuel-efficiency metrics of city-driving cycles, so it is not being ignored.

Comment: http://www.abc.net.au/news/2018-03-07/fact-check-does-corolla-emit-less-than-tesla/9461096 has some recent numbers and conservation leaning analysis

Answer (score 82, accepted):

If you asked about Nickel Metal Hybrid batteries, the answer would be extremely easy. A large amount of studies have been done with these, usually concluding that they have lifespan comparable to those internal combustion engine vehicles. To cite the [100,000-Mile Evaluation of the Toyota RAV4 EV study](http://www.evchargernews.com/miscfiles/sce-rav4ev-100k.pdf),

> The five-vehicle test is demonstrating the long-term durability of Nickel Metal Hydride batteries and
> of electric drive-trains. Only slight performance degradation has been observed to date with the
> highest mileage vehicles. Test data provide strong evidence that all five vehicles will exceed the
> 100,000-mile mark and SCE’s positive experience points to the very strong likelihood of a 130,000 to
> 150,000-mile battery and drive-train operational life. This is achieved by full or mostly full range use
> after every charge. EVs can therefore match or exceed the lifecycle miles of comparable internal
> combustion engine vehicles.

As such, the reduction of greenhouse gases is simply a net benefit for the environment. However, you asked for lithium-ion batteries. That makes the answer harder to answer. Lithium-ion batteries are used in hybrid cars since only very recently. Little information is available on the subject.

Don't take my word for it. It's the first thing said in [the only peer-reviewed study I could find on the subject](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/es903729a), published in August 2010:

> Battery-powered electric cars (BEVs) play a key role in future mobility scenarios. However, little is known about the environmental impacts of the production, use and disposal of the lithium ion (Li-ion) battery. This makes it difficult to compare the environmental impacts of BEVs with those of internal combustion engine cars (ICEVs).

The study made several assumptions that were favorable to ICEVs:

- Used a car more energy efficient than the average car sold in Europe in 2009. They used 5.2 L of gasoline per 100 km, instead of 5.7 L of diesel /100 km 6.6 L of gasoline /100 km.
- "All expenditures for the exploitation of the lithium salts were allocated to the lithium salts, even though the saline brine yields other byproduct as well."
- All the burden from production are allocated to the first life of each product even though the product might be reused or recycled. As explained in the study, this assumption heavily penalizes BEVs since recycling of electric batteries is high and since recycling of lithium is more energy efficient than production of it.

In spite of that, electric cars perform far better than conventional cars on all four indicators (abiotic depletion potential, global warming potential, cumulative energy demand, and eco-indicator 99):

[image]

In fact, the research concludes that

> All the facts taken together, the results of the LCA, the various sensitivity analyses, the modeling applied for EOL, the assumption for the used electricity mix, etc., suggest that E-mobility is environmentally beneficial compared to conventional mobility. The Li-ion battery plays a minor role in the assessment of the environmental burden of E-Mobility. Thus, a Li-ion battery in an BEV does not lead to an overcompensation of the potential benefits of the higher efficiency of BEV compared to an ICEV.

They note, however, that it's not always necessarily always the case. A few very small and efficient internal combustion engine vehicles can perform as well as electric cars:

> A break even analysis shows that an ICEV would need to consume less than 3.9 L/100km to cause lower CED than a BEV or less than 2.6 L/100km to cause a lower EI99 H/A score. Consumptions in this range are achieved by some small and very efficient diesel ICEVs, for example, from Ford and Volkswagen ([13](http://www.volkswagen.ch/ch/de/Volkswagen/Innovation/Bluemotion/bmt_modelle/golf.html), [39](http://www.ford.de/Pkw-Modelle/AlternativeAntriebe/FordECOnetic/tabid=tab1)).

They also note that the means by which the energy is produced influences the how environmentally-friendly BEVs are. The study used the average electricity production mix in Europe to give a general idea. If electricity comes from "an average hard coal power plant", the environmental burden is increased by 13.4%. On the other hand, if the electricity comes from hydropower plants, the environmental burden is decreased by 40.2%. As such, as countries move toward green energy, the environmental burden of electric cars will decrease.

The study does not address the cost of manufacturing the automobiles, but those costs are not significant. [As a recent Argonne National Lab study](http://www.transportation.anl.gov/pdfs/TA/378.PDF) concluded that, while hybrid cars cost more to produce, hybrid cars make up for their greater manufacture energy costs by being more environmentally-friendly on the road - especially if recycled materials are used in the vehicle's fabrication.

To cite the study's conclusion,

> The energy use and GHG emissions that result from vehicle production and disposal of advanced-powertrain vehicles (HEV and FCV) may be greater than those for ICEVs because of (1) the use of energyi-ntensive materials in the fuel cell system of the FCV, and (2) the increased use of aluminum in both the HEV and FCV. However, the use of recycled materials can reduce these impacts. Conversely, the use of energy-intensive materials such as aluminum and carbon fiber composites does not necessarily increase the vehicle-cycle energy use and GHG emissions of lightweight vehicles; with a reduction in total weight, the results are about the same and could be improved with additional recycling.
>
> To put vehicle-cycle results into a broad perspective, we conducted a total energy-cycle analysis that included the vehicle-cycle, fuel-cycle, and vehicle-operation stages. Our vehicle-cycle analysis revealed that lightweight materials can reduce the weight of a vehicle and improve its fuel economy, but that production of these materials can be energy intensive if recycled materials are not used. Our total energy-cycle analysis further shows that, when examining vehicle technologies and lightweight materials on a total energy-cycle basis, there can be a significant net benefit in terms of energy use and emissions reduction by substituting lightweight materials for conventional materials.

Comment: The quote about NMH batteries only covers their *production cost* though, right? They still have to be charged. Doesn’t this have to be considered in the energy consumption (and thus pollution) as well?

Comment: @KonradRudolph: The quote about NMH only talks about their lifespan. To answer your question, though, hybrid cars powered NHM batteries are also better for the environment than conventional cars.

Comment: The charging of NMH and LI batteries charge in the same way. There may be some differences in the power lost in the change, and in their lifecycle, but for the most part, they work just like the LI batteries.

Comment: @Borror0 *That*’s an interesting factoid that was (for me at least) missing. Great answer.

Comment: @Borror0 -- Nicely done, I read it all and all the references and it looks solid to me.  +1 (will see what shakes out before I accept as answer)

Comment: The Volkswagen link (which is now broken) here is for the Golf, but that didn't have the flagship fuel efficiency, it was the [2006 VW Polo Bluemotion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BlueMotion) with 3.9 L / 100 km.

Answer (score 11):

[This article](http://www.altenergystocks.com/archives/2010/01/lithiumion_batteries_are_too_valuable_to_waste_on_plugin_vehicles_1.html) explains that if the goal is to reduce aggregate gasoline consumption, the most savings is found by spreading smaller batteries over more cars, rather than larger batteries over few cars. This is because a scarcity of battery materials limits production.

The greatest savings-per-battery-materials comes from upgrading a gasoline car's battery such that it can handle the strain of turning the car off every time it stops. Upgrading N cars with such batteries saves more gasoline than upgrading proportionally fewer cars as hybrids or electrics.

Answer (score 10):

Even if you'd disregard how much pollution is created while making batteries, just the fuel efficiency of hybrid cars is actually much worse than that of modern eco-turbodiesel. Especially [VolksWagen's *BlueMotion*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BlueMotion) (aka *EcoMotive* in SEATs and *Greenline* in Škodas)  line of engines is exceptionally fuel efficient. Fuel efficiency translates to less pollution.

- Hybrid: **2010 Toyota Prius** —  [4.0 L/100 km (58.8 mpg<sub>us</sub>), CO<sub>2</sub> emission of 92g/km](http://carfueldata.direct.gov.uk/search-new-or-used-cars.aspx?vid=27182),
- Diesel: **2010 VolksWagen Polo** — [3.50 L/100km (67.2 mpg<sub>us</sub>), CO<sub>2</sub> emission of 91g/km;](http://carfueldata.direct.gov.uk/search-new-or-used-cars.aspx?vid=25449)

Comment: worse of course :) And he's taking the correct comparison vehicles for Europe, as many people would have purchased a car in the class of the VW Polo if it weren't for the tax credits on hybrids. Comparisons using similar sized cars rather than similar priced ones are invalid.

Comment: @jwenting: for example in the Netherlands these eco-diesels do get tax breaks, as that's based on CO2 emissions, rather than technology.

Comment: I already pointed that out in my answer...

Comment: @Bor: sorry, tl;dr

Comment: This answer incorrectly assumes that "hybrid" and "diesel" are exclusive. The peugeot 3008 is in fact available as a hybrid diesel.

Comment: @MS: no it doesn't assume it. It assumes, "diesel" in this context means "diesel-only" car, which isn't dragging along batteries and electric engine.

Comment: yes vartec, but they don't get nearly the same tax break as do hybrids. I live in the Netherlands myself, know the resulting pricing structures. Given the 2 cars mentioned here, the larger, less efficient, Prius is less expensive to drive (certainly for the corporate driver) than is the VW (and it's more prestigious too, being a larger car and one hailed as the saviour of the planet so many people would want one just to be seen in one).

Comment: @jw: fair enough, I haven't had looked at corporate market at all, AFAIK, for individual users both cars have 0 BPM (VW Polo Bluemotion: http://www.volkswagen.nl/home/modellen/polo/prijzen/0,18312,Polo_BlueMotion_D0Lnl,00.html)

Comment: @vartec then you need to compare it with a diesel hybrid, not a gas hybrid.  Diesel fuel has more energy in it than gas, which is why it gets higher mpg at optimal highway cruising speed.  It might have ever so slightly less CO2 emission, but has higher particulate and NOx emissions.

Comment: @vartec: for these cars, in the Netherlands, the corporate market accounts for something like 75-80% of sales (most ending up as leases, with 14 income tax addition for the hybrid, 20% for the gasoline, and 25% probably for a diesel, making the hybrid at the same catalogue price the cheapest option for the corporate driver even if the fuel cost to his employer is higher).

Comment: Does the VW diesel produce more, the same or less emissions than the Prius? Fuel efficiency is a happy biproduct of hybrids (and how the vehicles are marketed), however the primary purpose was to have low emissions.

Comment: @BryanH:  VW Polo with 1.2 Bluemotion TDI emits 87g/km CO₂ vs 89g/km for Prius. VW burns 3.0L/100km, Prius 3.9L/100km.

Comment: @BryanH and that's just CO2, which while the posterchild of the green lobby is utterly irrelevant compared to NOx, partially burnt carbohydrates, soot, SO2, etc. etc. all of which are now omitted from public emission charts so are impossible to compare.

Comment: If these are [NEDC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_European_Driving_Cycle) values ... they don't really reflect what the car would consume in live usage, or do they? (Point being: "Real" usage may scale differently for hybrid vs. normal engines depending on driving style.)

Comment: The points about VW diesels should probably be updated given the revelations regarding VW's gaming of emissions testing.

Comment: @JAB The VW revelations were mostly over NOx not MPG or CO2. Here's a quote from a [Reuters article](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-volkswagen-emissions-carbon/vw-says-co2-emissions-scandal-not-as-bad-as-feared-idUSKBN0TS12I20151209) *"Emissions of those models, including the 2.0 liter TDI Golf hatchback and the 2.0 liter TDI Passat, deviated on average by “a few grams” from what had been declared, corresponding to 0.1-0.2 liters of extra fuel usage per 100 kilometers, it said. "*