# Does an e-bike produces only 1/10 carbon emissions for each mile of an conventional electric car?

Tags: road-vehicles, environment, bicycles

According to Lin, Bo (Deputy General Director at Furi E-Bike<sup>1</sup>): he says the following in an interview in the program *Horizons* from WOBI:

> Bicycles to lead acid battery generates some pollution. The government has some regulations to limit bike lead-acid battery. But the lithium battery bicycles are much better, create less pollution and are lightweight.

To what the presenter says:

> with a load of 5-8 hours of an electrical connection in the wall of house, *average e-bike with lithium battery* should yield a coverage of 50 km, **producing only 1/10 of carbon emissions per mile of a conventional electric car.**

is this assertion accurate?

---

I couldn't find the episode online, but I recorded an video sample and [I had upload the part of the interview at MEGA](https://mega.nz/#!ucQzBCZA!Yz9b5Eu10hVtirASQghoCC4_T_vOulG31DpANX2CWNQ) *(low quality "especially the sound" and has subtitles in Spanish, but I hope that may count as the source of my question).*

I also found [similar](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/351/does-a-car-with-a-hybrid-engine-and-lithium-batteries-pollute-more-than-a-car-wi) [questions](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/25280/do-electric-cars-create-more-fine-dust-pollution-than-comparable-petrol-cars), but I consider *some* different from mine.

<sup>1</sup> The full name of the Chinnese company is [Tianjin Fushida Bicycle Co.](http://www.bloomberg.com/research/stocks/private/snapshot.asp?privcapId=28461163)

Comment: I could upload some screenshots of the interview, but, they're subtitled in Spanish and I can't find another or similar assertions.

Comment: I couldn't find any information about a company "Furi eBike" online. But there is a company called [Puri eBike](http://puriebike.com.au/). Are you maybe talking about them?

Comment: The file you linked to asks me for an decryption key which you didn't provide.

Comment: @Philipp, sorry about that, I have edited my question.

Comment: I have already accepted the only posted answer. **I'll offer another bounty once I can see more (answers) even more detailed.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Doesn't seem to be a much studied subject, but there's a study titled  [Electric Vehicles in China: Emissions and Health Impacts](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/51925588_Electric_Vehicles_in_China_Emissions_and_Health_Impacts)
 which also claims the emissions from eBikes are ~ 1/10th of those of eCars.

As the title suggests, the study is from a whole another field, but there's a section dealing with comparing emission levels from various forms of transportation in China, including electric vechiles. According to the study, medium emissions of CO2 for eCars are ~ 122 g/km-1 and ~ 18g/km-1 for eBikes respectively.

If that information might be of help, perhaps take a look for yourself, it won't take much time. [Link to PDF](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/es202347q)
Edit: link fixed

Comment: can you please elaborate a little bit more your answer?

Comment: @Mauricio Okay, answer edited

Comment: the link of the PDF file is broken: `Error 404 Not Found`. I appreciate your efforts for answer my question. I want also invite you to see the [tour of Skeptics.StackExchange.com](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/tour) for know how you can add more value to the community. I hope too that one of the moderators will give you a better welcome.