# Do "big-battery" electric vehicles release more CO2 than diesel equivalents over their lifetime?

Tags: road-vehicles, environment

[Autocar](https://www.autocar.co.uk/car-news/new-cars/mazda-favours-smaller-batteries-upcoming-evs) report that Mazda have made a surprising claim about electric vehicles with larger batteries (i.e. 95kWh):

> Mazda says it will never build a ‘big-battery’ electric car, because it believes such vehicles are less environmentally friendly than even conventional diesel-powered models, judged over a whole energy life cycle.
>
> Speaking in Portugal at a prototype test drive of the upcoming MX-30 electric car, Joachim Kunz, head of product development and engineering at Mazda Europe, said the firm has studied the CO2 emissions of building a vehicle “from extraction to disposal”.
>
> Citing a study by a Japanese university using the average CO2 output of the European grid, Kunz said an **EV with a 95kWh battery has such a disadvantage of embedded CO2 at the point of sale that a new Mazda Skyactiv diesel car will probably be more CO2 efficient across its lifetime**, even if the EV’s battery pack is not replaced at 100,000 miles.
>
> [image: Graph comparing CO2 emitted over lifecycle]

However, in this related question, *[Are electric cars beneficial to the environment compared to low consumption modern cars?](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/5617/are-electric-cars-beneficial-to-the-environment-compared-to-low-consumption-mode/32231#32231)*, the answer concludes electric cars have lower CO2 equivalent emissions, without discussion of the battery size.

I'm quite confused, where does the truth lie?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103506/discussion-on-question-by-dorminum-do-big-battery-electric-vehicles-release-mo).

Comment: If the disadvantage is caused by the C02 emissions from the grid, then _no_ Electric car would be beneficial, independent of it's battery size.