# Are Hummers more environmentally friendly than Prius?

Tags: technology, road-vehicles, energy-efficiency

I've heard this rumor a few times ([example](http://hardware.slashdot.org/story/07/03/20/1858204/Hummer-Greener-Than-Prius)).  The argument is that it takes energy to make the car, and when you take into account how long each car will last on the road, driving Prius's over a large number of miles will end up requiring *more* energy than if you had driven Hummers over that many miles.

This argument sounds dubious to me.  Is there any validity to this claim?

Comment: Similar question http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/351/does-a-car-with-a-hybrid-engine-and-lithium-batteries-pollute-more-than-a-car-wit

Comment: Similar argument is being made about energy-efficient computers.

Comment: I think Top Gear did provide evidence for a similar claim - but for one of the Mercedes exec saloons vs the Prius.

Comment: Top Gear is a great show, but they get it wrong all the time when it comes to this type of information.

Comment: Do you assume `less unfriendly == more friendly`? Assuming Hummers are `environmentally friendly` doesn't make much sense for me :)

Comment: Probably not, but they are probably more environmentally friendly than buses.

Comment: Two reports that point out the many flaws in the "Dust to Dust" report where this claim was made: 
[Hummer versus Prius: "Dust to Dust" report misleads the media and public with bad science](http://pacinst.org/publication/hummer-versus-prius-dust-to-dust-report-misleads-the-media-and-public-with-bad-science/) and [Dust to Dust's assumptions about the Prius and the Hummer](http://www.rmi.org/Knowledge-Center/Library/T07-01_AssumptionsPriusHummer)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The Straight Dope [reports](http://www.straightdope.com/columns/read/2759/are-electric-cars-really-more-energy-efficient) that while the full environmental impact is hard to measure, there is not much evidence to support the "Hummers are better for the environment than the Prius" claim:

> The cause of the controversy seems to be a report called "Dust to
>   Dust" by Oregon-based CNW Marketing Research. The report claims a
>   Prius has a higher lifetime energy cost than a Hummer, an assertion
>   cited by George Will in 2007 in his syndicated newspaper column. But
>   the report is ludicrous. It evidently was self-published, lists no
>   authors, quotes no technical literature, never explains its
>   methodology, and contains numerous unsupported and often bizarre
>   assertions.

Slate's Green Lantern also has a go at [answering](http://www.slate.com/id/2186786/) this question, and comes to much the same conclusion.

Comment: of course just measuring "energy cost" isn't going to provide the whole picture. There's also chemical pollution from things like heavy metals, complex carbohydrates, etc. during all stages of manufacturing, lifecycle, and recycling/deposition of the vehicle to take into account.

Comment: We will not know the full environmental impact of battery cars until they are sold by the hundreds of millions, just like fossil fuel cars. They all pollute, before, during and after they are gone from the roads. My bet is they are worse than fossil cars.

Comment: Also, selling any functional car to purchase a new, more environmentally friendly car, is a net harm for the environment.  The environmental consequences of driving that gas-guzzler for another ten years are less then the impact of building and driving a brand new Prius.

Comment: @Moab "_My bet is they are worse than fossil cars._" So which logical fallacy did you commit there? Personal Incredulity? Anecdotal?